# How to render angular material tags from JSON response inside angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, owl-carousel

I have a json response of like this

```
 {
      _id: '5dd0d0dc4db1cf9c77781aaa',
      picture: 'http://placehold.it/32x32',
      name: 'Graciela Mcmahon',
      guid: '98c0fcc2-1dfc-4974-bdae-d8263d783e0a',
      star:
        '<mat-icon>star</mat-icon><mat-icon>star</mat-icon><mat-icon>star_half</mat-icon><mat-icon>star_border</mat-icon><mat-icon>star_border</mat-icon>',
 }
```

When i render start it did not render as expected
my component code

```
<owl-carousel-o [options]="listingSliderOptions" class="row">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let listing of listingJson">
      <ng-template carouselSlide [id]="listing._id">
        <a [routerLink]="['/']" class="listing-grid-item">
          <figure>
            <img src="{{listing.picture}}" alt="" />
            <div class="info">
              <div class="cat_star" [innerHTML]="listing.star">

              </div>
              <h3>{{listing.name}}</h3>
            </div>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
  </owl-carousel-o>
```

The above code display as 
[image]

Is this right way to display or i have to generate tag inside Angular component ?

Expected Result

[image]

Comment: You say it did not render as expected, but nowhere do you indicate what you *do* expect...

Comment: I edited my question https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGAZA.png  @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: No, you can't do that. Don't put Angular HTML markup in your JSON. Put data. In this case, the number of stars to be displayed. And in your component template, put the code necessary to disply that number of stars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

Your problem stems from the fact that you are trying to dynamically load a component in runtime. This can't be expected to happen with pure html.

Read [this article here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) for dynamic component loading. `mat-icon` is not an html element so the browser does not know what to do with it, thus you have this weird outcome.

It is also a very bad security practice to load html in your application, that comes from an api as malicious code and html could be injected.

### Solution

Send the stars as a number from your backend. Create an ngFor with mat-icon defined in it and iterate as many times as you want to create the stars.

```
<div class="cat_star">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let star of listing.star">
          <mat-icon>{{ star }}</mat-icon>
      </ng-container>
 </div>
```